# Why we solve the dual problem in SVM?

Tags: svm, optimization, kernel-trick

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why bother with the dual problem when fitting SVM?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19181/why-bother-with-the-dual-problem-when-fitting-svm)

What advantages do we get from solving in the dual?