# Calculate number of support vectors in SVM

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, svm, kernel-trick

I provided my current (partial) solution, and I hope someone can correct me and/or give me suggestions as to how I should solve the parts that I've left out.

> Given an SVM with kernel:
>
> $$K(x,z) = \theta(x)^T \theta(z) = 
>   \left\{
>   \begin{array}{ll}
>       1   & \text{if } x = z  \\
>       0   & \text{otherwise}
>   \end{array}
>   \right.$$
>
> We are given $N$ training examples $(x_1, y_1) \ldots (x_N, y_N)$ with $y_i = \pm 1$. For simplicity, assume that the $x_i$'s are distinct, and that we only consider the SVM where the hyperplane in the feature space goes through the origin, i.e., the intercept $b=0$.
>
> 1. Recall the weight vector $w$ used in SVM has the form
>      $$w = \sum_{i=1}^N \alpha_i y_i \theta(x_i)$$
>      Compute the $\alpha_i$'s explicitly that would be found using SVMs with this kernel.
> 2. Recall that the SVM algorithm outputs a classifier that, on input $x$, computes the sign of $w^T \theta(x)$. What is the value of this inner product on the training example $x_i$? What is the value of this inner product on any example $x$ not seen during training? Based on these answers, what kind of generalization error do you expect will be achieved by SVMs using this kernel?
> 3. Recall that the generalization error of SVMs can be bounded using the margin $\delta$ (which is equal to $1/\|w\|$), or using the number of support vectors. What is $\delta$ in this case? How many support vectors are there in this case? How are these answers consistent with your answer in part (2)?

For part (1), I maximized the dual form of the objective function
$$
\max_{\alpha} \sum_{n=1}^N \alpha_n - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^N \sum_{m=1}^N y_n y_m \alpha_n \alpha_m K(x_n, x_m)
$$
subject to the constraints $\alpha_n \geq 0, n=1,\ldots,N$ and $\sum_{n=1}^N \alpha_n y_n = 0$. I did that by forming the Lagrangian
$$
\mathcal{L}(\alpha, \beta, \lambda) = \sum_{n=1}^N \alpha_n - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^N \sum_{m=1}^N y_n y_m \alpha_n \alpha_m K(x_n, x_m) - \sum_{n=1}^N \beta_n \alpha_n - \lambda \sum_{n=1}^N \alpha_n y_n
$$
then taking the derivative with respect to $\alpha_i$, and setting it to zero.
The solution I got for $\alpha_i$ is 
$$
\alpha_i = \frac{1}{y_i} \left[ \frac{1}{y_i} - \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{y_n}\right]
$$

For part (2), I started by replacing my $\alpha_i$ found in part (1) into the inner product
$$
w^T \theta(x) = \sum_{j=1}^N \alpha_j y_j \theta(x_j)^T \theta(x)
$$
When $x_i$ is in the training set, i get
$$
w^T \theta(x_i) = \frac{1}{y_i} - \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{y_n}
$$

When $x$ is not in the training set, i get 
$$
w^T \theta(x) = 0
$$

Is it true that this shows that the kernel will yield a poor generalization performance? Is there any way I can show it formally?

Finally, for part (3), I got $\delta$ by
$$
\delta = \frac{1}{\|w\|} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^N \alpha_n^2 y_n^2}}
$$

How do I calculate the number of support vectors? And how does this relate to part (b)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that since $y_{i} = \pm 1$, you can rewrite,
$$
\alpha_i = \frac{1}{y_i} \left[ \frac{1}{y_i} - \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{y_n}\right] = y_i \left[y_i - \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N y_n\right] = 1 - y_{i}\frac{N^{+}-N^{-}}{N}
$$
where $N^{+}$ and $N^{-}$ are the number of samples in each of the classes. You can check that $\sum_{n}\alpha_{n}y_{n} = 0$. Also $\alpha_{n} > 0$, that is, all vectors are support vectors.

As for the margin,
$$
||\omega|| = \sum_{n}\alpha^{2} = N\left[1-\left(\frac{N^{+}-N^{-}}{N}\right)^{2}\right]
$$

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that for such a kernel, for all non-data points, $z$, you will get $w^T\theta(z) = \sum_i \alpha_i k(x_i, z) = 0$. For intuition, note that your kernel is equivalent to the RBF kernel with width converging to 0. Thus, you have no generalization capability at all; the decision function is based on 0-radius balls.